# Zipkin not working in Docker - conncection refused

Tags: spring-boot, docker, rabbitmq, microservices, zipkin

Zipkin works well locally but not in docker container. All the microservices are registered well in the Eureka and they can communicate well. But the only problem is Zipkin. I am getting the following error:

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
> POST request for "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": Connect to
> http://localhost:9411 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused

my docker-compose.yaml is as follows:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  currency-exchange:
    image: samankt/springboot-udemy-currency-exchange:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    mem_limit: 512m
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    networks:
      - saman-network  
    environment:
      EUREKA.CLIENT.SERVICE-URL.DEFAULTZONE: http://naming-server:8761/eureka
      EUREKA.INSTANCE.PREFERIPADDRESS: true  
      SPRING.ZIPKIN.BASE-URL: http://zipkin-server:9411/
      RABBIT_URI: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
      SPRING_ZIPKIN_SENDER_TYPE: rabbit
    depends_on:
      - naming-server
      - rabbitmq
      
  api-gateway:
    image: samankt/springboot-udemy-currency-api-gateway:0.0.1-snapshot
    mem_limit: 512m
    ports:
      - '8765:8765'
    networks:
      - saman-network  
    environment:
      EUREKA.CLIENT.SERVICE-URL.DEFAULTZONE: http://naming-server:8761/eureka
      EUREKA.INSTANCE.PREFERIPADDRESS: true  
      SPRING.ZIPKIN.BASE-URL: http://zipkin-server:9411/
      RABBIT_URI: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
      SPRING_ZIPKIN_SENDER_TYPE: rabbit 
    depends_on:
      - naming-server
      - rabbitmq
      
  currency-converter:
    image: samankt/currency-conversion:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    mem_limit: 700m
    ports:
      - '8100:8100'
    networks:
      - saman-network  
    environment:
      EUREKA.CLIENT.SERVICE-URL.DEFAULTZONE: http://naming-server:8761/eureka
      EUREKA.INSTANCE.PREFERIPADDRESS: true  
      SPRING.ZIPKIN.BASE-URL: http://zipkin-server:9411/
      SPRING.ZIPKIN.DISCOVERYCLIENTENABLED: true 
      RABBIT_URI: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
      SPRING_ZIPKIN_SENDER_TYPE: rabbit     
    depends_on:
      - naming-server
      - rabbitmq
      
  naming-server:
    image: samankt/naming-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    mem_limit: 512m
    ports:
      - '8761:8761'
    environment:
      SPRING.ZIPKIN.BASE-URL: http://zipkin-server:9411/    
    networks:
      - saman-network
      
  zipkin-server:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin:latest
    mem_limit: 400m
    ports:
      - '9411:9411'
    networks:
      - saman-network   
    environment:
      RABBIT_URI: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    restart: always
      
      
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.12-management
    ports:
      - '5672:5672'
      - '15672:15672'
    networks:
      - saman-network
    
networks: 
  saman-network:
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## SOLUTION 1

The error is telling you that the connection on `http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans` is refused. When you run your application inside a docker container you need to send the request not with localhost, but through the docker network (in your case saman-network). To access the docker container which runs zipkin you need to send the request to `http://zipkin-server:9411/api/v2/spans`.

From Spring Boot 3 Sleuth is deprecated and you will need to use [micrometer](https://spring.io/blog/2022/10/12/observability-with-spring-boot-3).
To use tracing with zipkin you can add the following 4 dependencies to you `pom.xml` file

```xml
<dependency>
     <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
     <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-observation-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Finally to change the Zipkin endpoint to send the tracing information you need to add the following to your application.yaml file.

```yaml
management:
  tracing:
    sampling:
      probability: 1.0 # only for testing purpose, switch back to 0.1 for production code
  zipkin:
    tracing:
      endpoint: http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans
```

It is good practice to use Spring profiles, therefore you copy your
`application.yaml` file and name it `application-docker.yaml`. In this new file you can modify the Zipkin endpoint with the zipkin container name `zipkin-server`.

```yaml
management:
  tracing:
    sampling:
      probability: 1.0 # only for testing purpose, switch back to 0.1 for production code
  zipkin:
    tracing:
      endpoint: http://zipkin-server:9411/api/v2/spans
```

You can activate the Spring profiles passing `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVATE=docker` in the environment.

---

## SOLUTION 2

For you this solution is faster to implement but I didn't test it. You pass the Zipkin url as an environment value `SPRING.ZIPKIN.BASE-URL` inside the `docker-compose.yml`.
This property was used with the Sleuth package. With Spring Boot 3 and micrometer try to pass instead: `MANAGEMENT.ZIPKIN.TRACING.ENDPOINT:  http://zipkin-server:9411/api/v2/spans`

Comment: If you're interested in more zipkin properties with spring boot 3 the class [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.tracing.zipkin.ZipkinProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/3860eb211af1b429f325c05408ba2ebc82ae6698/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/tracing/zipkin/ZipkinProperties.java) defines them.

Comment: Thanks @mini for your great solutions. In the first solution, you truly mentioned the problem in calling zipkin endpoint. But as you can see I changed the endpoint call by passing the right one into the SPRING.ZIPKIN.BASE-URL , but it seems that it does not work and localhost is called by default! I have not applied micormeter yet but going to test it as you recommended. I will inform you accordingly. The second solution points to the assignment of the environment variable of SPRING.ZIPKIN.BASE-UR that I did already but the problem persisted. Spring profile use is a great recommendation.

Comment: I was using `zipkin-reporter-brave` and `micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave` with Spring Boot 3.0.3. I can confirm that setting `MANAGEMENT.ZIPKIN.TRACING.ENDPOINT` solved my problem. Thanks :-)

Comment: Setting `MANAGEMENT.ZIPKIN.TRACING.ENDPOINT` is the right answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my Spring Boot 3 project, I encountered the same kind of issue, and the following solution worked for me:

I added the following dependencies to my project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-observation</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In my Docker Compose file, I set the environment variable as follows:

```
services:
  currency-exchange:
    image: XX
    ports:
      - XX
    networks:
      - XX
    depends_on:
      - XX
    environment:
      MANAGEMENT.ZIPKIN.TRACING.ENDPOINT:  http://zipkin-server:9411/api/v2/spans
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved when I downgraded to Spring 2.x from 3.0.

It seems that Zipkin does not work well with Spring 3.0 currently. The problem is for docker, not local running. I could not find enough resources to support this idea. But in my experience, this is the case. I tried Zipkin with "latest" tag with Spring 3.0.0 but the problem persists. But it does work well with Spring 2.x